# .indexOn Firebase iOS

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is the data structure layout. I have multiple groups and under each groups there are multiple payments

```
{
  "RE_PAYMENTS" : {
"AF04BDB4-6AF4-43F1-A084-D215AD0C992D" : {  
  "B73FBFB1-2615-4F42-A7C6-3CA4B2B4BCDF" : { 
    "PAYMENT_DETAIL" : {
      "paymentAmount" : 20,
      "paymentCurrency" : "USD",
      "paymentDate" : "1461525157.150915"
    }
  },
  "B8B0FDF3-4458-4AE2-B1A0-9DCD8ACFF422" : {
    "PAYMENT_DETAIL" : {
      "paymentAmount" : 40,
      "paymentCurrency" : "USD",
      "paymentDate" : "1461525392.178588"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

From the structure above "AF04B......" is the groupId and there will be multiple groups with payments under it.

Here is how I've written my rules.

[image]

I still keep getting the Xcode warning

```
[Firebase] Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "PAYMENT_DETAIL/paymentDate" at /RE_PAYMENTS/AF04BDB4-6AF4-43F1-A084-D215AD0C992D to your security rules for better performance
```

I have followed the documentation and I am trying to keep the structure as flat as possible. Any tips on resolving this indexOn issue ? I cannot hardcode the groupId or the paymentId with the index rule.

Here is the code that triggers this warning (eventType is FEventTypeChildAdded or FEventTypeChildChanged or FEventTypeChildRemoved)

```
FQuery* query = [self queryRefForPaymentsForGroup:groupId];
[query observeEventType:eventType withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot)
 {}
```

And the query is created as

```
// I have just pasted the value here but the path is created using 'childByAppendingPath'
Firebase *groupRef = @"https://xxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/RE_PAYMENTS/AF04BDB4-6AF4-43F1-A084-D215AD0C992D";   

FQuery* query = [[[groupRef queryOrderedByChild:@"PAYMENT_DETAIL/paymentDate"] queryStartingAtValue:startDateQueryString] queryEndingAtValue:endDateQueryString];
```

Here is the Xcode console for the query

[image]

All I'm trying to do is query for a list of payments under a group within a set of dates.

Comment: What code triggers the error. In addition: you've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question and other text. Please replace those with the actual text. You can easily get the JSON by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ... I've added the details you asked for. Appreciate your help. I'm migrating my app from parse and I'd love to get this working.